# rasa init --no-prompt throwing import error

Tags: rasa

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\runpy.py",
ne 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\runpy.py",
ne 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\rasaa\Scripts\rasa.exe\__main__.py", line 4,
<module>
  File "c:\users\lenovo\desktop\rasaa\lib\site-packages\rasa\__init__.py", li
8, in <module>
    from rasa.run import run
  File "c:\users\lenovo\desktop\rasaa\lib\site-packages\rasa\run.py", line 5,
 <module>
    from rasa.cli.utils import print_warning
  File "c:\users\lenovo\desktop\rasaa\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\utils.py", l
 12, in <module>
    from typing import NoReturn
ImportError: cannot import name 'NoReturn'
```

I am getting the above error i have used the virtual environment for this but still i am getting the errror my python version is 3.6

Answer (score 1):

There is no **NoReturn** special type in the **typing**  module for python version older than the 3.6.5 (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html)

I had the same issue while using python 3.6.1 version. It was solved after I started using the 3.6.8 version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using python 3.6.0 version. It was solved after I started using the 3.6.8 version python.